# Google clone exercise, why can´t i align the content?

Tags: html

I´m new to web development, like I just did 3h and am trying to finish a google clone as an exercise and I don´t seem to understand much about how the things relate.
I tried adopting several type of positions for the divs and buttons but nothing seems to change for the search field and the 2 buttons below.
running out of ideas.
Can you perhaps tell me which style rules are clashing with each other?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#Search {
  margin: 150px auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.holder {
  text-align: center;
}
.loginbutton {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.gbutton1 {
  background-color: lightGrey;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
.gbutton2 {
  background-color: lightGrey;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My crappy Google</title>
  <meta name="author" content="n00b">
</head>

<body>
  <button class="loginbutton">Login</button>

  <div id="Search">
    <div class="holder">
      <img src="https://www.google.at/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google Logo" width="75% of window">
    </div>

    <div class "box">
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search....">
    </div>


    <div>
      <button class="gbutton1">Google-search</button>
      <button class="gbutton2">i´m feeeling like crap</button>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>

</body>

</html>
```